# Django call_command permissions nginx+gunicorn+supervisord

Tags: django

I have installed this https://github.com/andybak/django-backup

App just provides `backup` management command

What i do:

**1.** `$ python manage.py backup`

*Everything is fine. Backup created!*

**2.** `$ python manage.py shell`

```py
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('backup')
```

*Everything is fine. Backup created!*

**3.** I've created view:

```py
from django.core.management import call_command

def backup(request): # /admin/backup/
    call_command('backup')
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

**4.** `$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9999`

Go to browser **mywebsite.com:9999/admin/backup/**

*Everything is fine. Backup created!*

**5.** But when I run my website through nginx+gunicorn+supervisord and go to browser **mywebsite.com/admin/backup/** - backup file is empty.

Maybe it is all about permissions? Please help.

Django 1.7

---

**EDIT:**

**6.** `/var/env/project/bin/gunicorn core.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:9999 --user=root --group=root` and go to browser **mywebsite.com:9999/admin/backup/**

*Everything is fine. Backup created!*

---

**/etc/supervisord.conf:**

```
[program:project]
command=/var/env/project/bin/gunicorn core.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --user=root --group=root
directory=/var/www/project/
environment=PATH="/var/env/project/bin/activate",DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="core.settings_prod"
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

Comment: yes, it's probably related to permission, check which user is used by gunicorn

Comment: user in gunicorn.conf

Comment: which user is executing the gunicorn and with which user do you test it manually?

Comment: manually: root ; I don't have gunicorn.conf, but in /etc/supervisord.conf: user=root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Mistake in supervisord.conf `environment=PATH=` it should be `environment=PYTHONPATH=`

```
environment=PYTHONPATH="/var/env/project/bin/activate",DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="core.settings_prod"
```