# Python Django call_command permissions gunicorn+nginx

Tags: nginx, permissions, gunicorn, manage.py, django-commands

#### Problem

Receive 502 bad gateway when i try to execute a django management command via gunicorn

#### Logic Line

I think the problem is about permissions, something like **gunicorn** is not able call the command. I say that because i can run it locally where i don't use gunicorn.

I can run it in these two methods:

- `python manage.py runserver` and after that, fire it using Postman and that's ok.
- The second one is calling by terminal `python manage.py command_name` and that's ok also.
- On production, i'm also able to run with `python manage.py command_name`. But not by postman, because it return 502 (the main problem)

**PS.** If i remove `call_command` it returns 200 ok, so, it seems like the core problem is the execution of this command.

#### The code

```py
class TestCommandView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        id = request.data['id']

        try:
            call_command('command_name', target_id=id)
            return Response({"status": "success"})
        except Exception as error:
            return Response({"status": "error: " + str(error) })
```

#### Return sample

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center>
            <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
        <center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Gunicorn Conf

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/project
ExecStart=/var/www/project/venv/bin/ddtrace-run /var/www/project/venv/bin/guni$
Environment="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.prod"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### Nginx Log error

```
2019/03/13 13:43:38 [error] 27552#27552: *3128 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: IP, server: api.project.com, request: "POST /api/project/endpoint/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/project.sock:/api/project/endpoint/", host: "api.project.com"
```

#### What i've tried

- `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/project`
- `sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www/project`
- Change my Environment value on **gunicorn** config based on this question solution: [Django call_command permissions nginx+gunicorn+supervisord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302806/django-call-command-permissions-nginxgunicornsupervisord). Adding **PYTHONPATH**, but this guy use it on **supervisor** config, this project don't use **supervisor**, so i tried to put it on **gunicorn** file, it was just a try.

Comment: Have you checked error logs for nginx?

Comment: Yes @Mahendra i will update the question with log

Comment: What about the logs for gunicorn itself? What do they say?

Comment: I realized it was a problem of gunicorn+nginx timeout. Thank you guys for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I realized it was a problem of timeout

The default timeout of **gunicorn** is 30 seconds based on its documentation.

[Doc.](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout) *Workers silent for more than this many seconds are killed and restarted.*

My request get more than 30 seconds, so, **gunicorn** killed the process and **nginx** returned 502.

#### Solution

- Change **gunicorn** default timeout
- Change nginx timeout

#### Gunicorn

I added the timeout option to **gunicorn ExecStart** line

**--timeout 300**

```
    ExecStart=/var/www/project/venv/bin/ddtrace-run /var/www/project/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/project.sock project.wsgi:application --access-logfile /home/ubuntu/gunicorn.log --error-logfile /home/ubuntu/gunicorn.error.log --timeout 720 --workers 3
```

#### Nginx

Added this option to HTTP part of nginx conf

```
proxy_read_timeout 300s;
```

Restarted **nginx** and **gunicorn** and that's worked like a charm